# Sql Join taking a lot of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am tying to execute this query but it is taking more than 5 hours, but the data base size is just 20mb. this is my code. Here I am joining 11 tables with reg_id. I need all columns with distinct values. Please guide me how to rearrange the query.

```
SELECT * 

FROM degree

JOIN diploma 
 ON degree.reg_id = diploma.reg_id
JOIN further_studies 
 ON diploma.reg_id = further_studies.reg_id
JOIN iti 
 ON further_studies.reg_id = iti.reg_id
JOIN personal_info 
 ON iti.reg_id = personal_info.reg_id
JOIN postgraduation 
 ON personal_info.reg_id = postgraduation.reg_id
JOIN puc 
 ON postgraduation.reg_id = puc.reg_id
JOIN skills 
 ON puc.reg_id = skills.reg_id
JOIN sslc 
 ON skills.reg_id = sslc.reg_id
JOIN license 
 ON sslc.reg_id = license.reg_id
JOIN passport 
 ON license.reg_id = passport.reg_id
GROUP BY fullname
```

Please help me if I did any mistake

Comment: Please also add the output of `DESCRIBE tablename` for each of the tables, and `EXPLAIN querycode` for your query above. The most likely cause is misused indices.

Comment: You are selecting all, why the GROUP BY? And need more details.

Comment: @Metaphor i am using GROUP BY for getting distinct value

Comment: Not enough information. Try the joins in a proper sequence. e.g. Pseudo Code: User JOIN Students............. do not JOIN Students JOIN User etc @VijaySebastian . If still not clear share the ERD Diagram. So that your problem gets resolved quicker

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The first problem with your query is that you are using `select *` with `group by fullname`.  You have zillions of columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  Unless you really, really, really know what you are doing (which I doubt), this is the wrong way to write a query.

Your performance problem is undoubtedly due to cartesian products and lack of indexes.  You are joining across different dimensions -- such as skills and degrees.  The result is a product of all the possibilities.  For some people, the data size can grow and grow and grow.

And then, the question is:  do you have indexes on the keys used in the joins?  For performance, you generally want such indexes.

Comment: @Amadan i can see cases when trade off of having indices is worse than not having them, ie extensive inserts vs rare reads etc

Comment: I could argue then that, if the throughput of inserts is that big, the database itself is *huge* - and then you really don't want to be doing any joins on it at all without indices, not only infrequent ones. Switch indices off for high-volume inserts, reenable indices for query; or live without joins. Then again, you might know something I don't...

Comment: @Amadan . . . In general, the index on only one table is used for a join.  So, you don't need indexes on both keys.  But why bother second guessing the optimizer?  Put an index on both and let the optimizer choose.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to get all columns of all tables

Comment: @VijaySebastian . . . Start with one table.  Add one table at a time, including the columns that you need.  You will quickly find that you are getting way more records than you intend.  At that point, you might figure out what to do.  Otherwise, ask another question with sample data and desired results (for the simpler query).

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem is in the query.First make sure **group by fullname** and try to give some **column names instead of ***.